# NamedQuery com Coleção como Parâmetro

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, parâmetros, collection

Eu estou usando as **NamedQuery** do **JPA**, para criar um DTO. E na minha **Query** eu tenho como condição um **IN** e como parâmetro do **IN** tem valores com espaços em branco no meio. (Ex: 9292  929). e esses valores com espaço em branco, não retorna nada. Somente valores sem espaço em branco.

```
@Query("SELECT NEW br.com.dto.LancamantoDto(m.id, r.id) \n" +
        "FROM Lancamento l \n" +
        "WHERE l.seuNumero IN  (:seuNumero) \n" +
        "AND   l.data       =   :data")
List<LancamentoDto> findAllBySeuNumeroAndData(@Param("seuNumero")List<String> seuNumero, @Param("data")LocalDate data);
```

Comment: Olá Danilo. `Lancamento.seuNumero` é uma `String`? Se for um `Number` (`Integer`, `BitInteger`, etc) você vai precisar passar uma lista do respectivo tipo. E.g., `List<Integer> seuNumero`.

Comment: Olá Anthony, no momento que chamo o método, eu passo uma List<String> mas dentro dessa List, tem valores que tem espaços em branco no meio, e é necessário esse espaços em branco no número.(Ex: 8283E   3434), quando eu preciso buscar apenas um Lancamento.seuNumero eu tenho que utilizar LIKE na Query, com wildcards % nos espaços em branco, mas para coleção não sei oque preciso fazer.

Comment: Olá Danilo, minha pergunta é sobre o tipo de `Lancamento.seuNumero`, o que vai determinar como essa lista é interpretada é o tipo do `l.seuNumero`. Isso é uma `String` no seu pojo mapeado?

Comment: Então @Anthony o `Lancamento.seuNumero` é String sim.

Comment: E no banco de dados esse valor é um `VARCHAR`? Se sim e as duas Strings estão iguais, deveria ser possível fazer uma consulta com `=` ou `IN` sem problemas.

Comment: Uma verificação simples. O nome no SELECT é `Lancamanto`, com A mesmo? Pode ser só um erro de digitação, mas não custa validar.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly sim, no banco de dados é varchar, e se eu realizo essa consulta direto no banco (SQL Server) funciona normal com os espaços em branco.

Comment: Danilo. Muito, muito estranho mesmo, principalmente o fato de consultas simples com `=` não funcionarem. Parece que seus valores estão sendo convertidos ou que o *encoding* está se perdendo... Já tentou criar algumas entradas em que `seuNumero` é igual a um punhado de caracteres (e.g. `ç$%€`) e checar se a consulta funciona do lado do hibernate?

Comment: Talvez o Spring Data esteja fazendo alguma coisa estranha também. Tente transformar sua consulta em uma `@NamedQuery` e utilizar a API padrão do Hibernate (e.g., `session.getNamedQuery`).

Comment: Fiz os teste, colocando um seuNumero com caracteres especial, e ele encontrou normal, via NamedQuery, e pela API padrao do Hibernate. Mas percebi uma coisa que quando o valor do `seuNumero`, tem apenas 1 espaço em branco( e.g. `127999 00 00 00001`) ele me retorna o registro, mas quando tento passar um `seuNumero` com mais de 1 espaço em branco (e.g. `128384       00 00 00001`) ele ignora esse `seuNumero`. Muito estranho isso.

Comment: Interessante. Mesmo pela API padrão? Quem sabe se você copiar a combinação do banco para o código `128384       00 00 00001`, já vi casos de caracteres que parecem espaços mas não são.

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe correta (JPQL Snippet) para IN com Collections deve ser escrito sem parenteses:

```
Query("SELECT NEW br.com.dto.LancamantoDto(m.id, r.id) \n" +
        "FROM Lancamento l \n" +
        "WHERE l.seuNumero IN  :seuNumero \n" +
        "AND   l.data       =   :data")
```

Existia [um bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5126) no hibernate a um tempo atras, parece que voltou a aparecer em uma versão nova (4.3).